# Unpivot table in power bi using DAX(direct query)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table like below:

```
product month1  month2
abc      10      40
def      20      50
rty      30      60
```

Output desired is:

```
Product month   demand 
abc     month1   10
def     month1   20
rty     month1   30
abc     month2   40
def     month2   50
rty     month   60
```

I tried with UNION and Select columns functions in dax but not working.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to achieve this in DAX and use one of:

Option A: Use the PowerQuery editor

[image]

Option B: If you are using a SQL source, do the UnPivot in your query.

[See here for an example](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/unpivot-in-sql/)

```
- Sql Server UNPIVOT Example
SELECT [Product Name]
      ,[Order Year]
      ,[Order Quantity]
FROM [SQL UnPivot Source]
UNPIVOT (
          [Order Quantity] FOR [Order Year] 
          IN ([2011],[2012],[2013],[2014]) 
    ) AS [UNPIVOT TABLE]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. We cant use power query since it will lead to import mode which is not allowed . and regarding SQL part, it looks great but unfortunately data from excel. hence cant use that

Comment: You cannot do Direct Query to Excel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources

Comment: correct. we have a function in dax named as unpivot and selectedcolumns for the same. but i am unable to use